# Why can't I access my lisp server when launched from the emacs repl

Tags: repl, xml, sly

I have a lisp xml-rpc server. When I launch it from a repl in a terminal, the server responds to the client's requests but when this server is launched from the sly repl in Emacs, the client is stuck waiting.

I don't understand why this happens...

EDIT (yes it wasn't clear):
I use s-xml-rpc, https://s-xml-rpc.common-lisp.dev/

In the sly-mrepl for sbcl, if I define a function like this :

```
(defun s-xml-rpc-exports::|lisp.GCD| (m n)
  (gcd m n))
```

and then I start the server in the sly-mrepl:

```
  (setq *xml-server* (s-xml-rpc:start-xml-rpc-server :port 6665 ))
```

from a client written in python :

```
import xmlrpclib

print(xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:6665/RPC2").lisp.GCD(12155, 130130))
```

the client remains blocked without a response from the server.

but

but if I do the same thing but from a sbcl repl launched from the terminal, the server answers and the client displays 715

Comment: Hi VaK. You will get better answers if you include details. Which CL? On which platform? Which XML-RPC server? Which CLI client, and what does its output look like? Which version of sly? Is there *any* output? Which version of Emacs? On which platform? Any or all of these *could* be decisive.

Comment: Can you see the server with `netstat -plan` or similar? Is there any way to turn on logging by the server to see what it's doing?

Comment: yes i can see the server with netstat